# Proof of convergence for integral remainder term of Maclaurin expansion

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I would like to know if, whenever $-r < x < r$,

$$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \displaystyle\int_0^x (t-x)^n \left(\frac{\mathrm d^{n+1}}{\mathrm dx^{n+1}} \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} \right){\Huge|}_{x=t} \; \mathrm dt = 0$$

where $n \in \mathbb N.$ I have only been able to brute force it with an numerical approach and the limit seems to be correct. For example: with $n=30$ and $r=1$, we see see that the expression is "small".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> I would like to know if, whenever $\ds{-r < x < r}$,
>   
>   $\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n!}\int_{0}^{x}
> \pars{t - x}^{n}\,
> \left.\totald[n + 1]{\pars{\root{r^{2} - y^{2}}}}{y}
> \right\vert_{\ y\ =\ t}\,\dd t} = 0:\ {\Large ?}.\quad}$ Note that $\ds{r > 0}$.

\begin{align}
&{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n!}\int_{0}^{x}
\pars{t - x}^{n}\,
\left.\totald[n + 1]{\pars{\root{r^{2} - y^{2}}}}{y}
\right\vert_{\ y\ =\ t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over n!}\int_{0}^{x}
\pars{x - t}^{n}\,\totald[n + 1]{\pars{\root{r^{2} - t^{2}}}}{t}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
{r \over n!}\int_{0}^{x}
\pars{x - t}^{n}\,\totald[n + 1]{}{t}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
{1/2 \choose k}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over r^{2k}}\,t^{2k}\,\dd t
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> Note that
>   $\ds{\left.\totald[m]{z^{s}}{z}\right\vert_{\ m, s\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{\ \geq\ 1}} =
> s\pars{s - 1}\ldots\pars{s - m + 1}z^{s - m} =
> {s! \over \pars{s - m}!}\,z^{s - m}}$

---

Moreover,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{x}\pars{x - t}^{n}\,\totald[n + 1]{t^{2k}}{t} & =
\int_{0}^{x}\pars{x - t}^{n}
\braces{\bracks{2k - n - 1 \geq 0}{\pars{2k}! \over \pars{2k - n - 1}!}
\,t^{2k - n - 1}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{k \geq {n + 1 \over 2}}{\pars{2k}! \over \pars{2k - n - 1}!}\,x^{2k}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}t^{2k - n - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{n}\,\dd t}
^{\ds{\Gamma\pars{2k - n}\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{2k + 1}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{k \geq \left\lfloor{n + 1 \over 2}\right\rfloor}
{\pars{2k}! \over \pars{2k - n - 1}!}\,x^{2k}\,
{\pars{2k - n - 1}!\,n! \over \pars{2k}!}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{k \geq \left\lfloor{n + 1 \over 2}\right\rfloor}n!\,x^{2k}\label{3}\tag{3}
\end{align}

---

With \eqref{3}, it turns out that
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n!}\int_{0}^{x}
\pars{t - x}^{n}\,
\left.\totald[n + 1]{\pars{\root{r^{2} - y^{2}}}}{y}
\right\vert_{\ y\ =\ t}\,\dd t}
\\[5mm] = &\
r\lim_{n \to \infty}
\sum_{k = n}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}z^{k}\,,\qquad
z \equiv \pars{x \over r}^{2}
\\[5mm] &
\mbox{Note that}\quad
\bbox[#ffe,10px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{\large{0 < z < 1}}}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n!}\int_{0}^{x}
\pars{t - x}^{n}\,
\left.\totald[n + 1]{\pars{\root{r^{2} - y^{2}}}}{y}
\right\vert_{\ y\ =\ t}\,\dd t}
\\[5mm] = &\
r\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\pars{-1}^{n}z^{n}
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose k + n}\pars{-1}^{k}z^{k}}
\end{align}

> The 'main contribution' to the above sum comes from $\ds{k \approx 0}$. Indeed, 
>   as $\ds{n \to \infty}$, $\ds{{1/2 \choose k + n} \sim
> {\pars{-1}^{k + n + 1} \over 2\root{\pi}}\,{1 \over n^{3/2}}}$ such that the final limit, as $\ds{n \to \infty}$ is
>   $\ds{\bbox[10px,#fee,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{\LARGE 0}}}$.